# Using interfaces to pass data from exe to dll in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, interface, callback, access-violation

I'm trying to pass an array of strings from host EXE to DLL in a loop. The host EXE is an external app which supports scripts (compiled and executed by a delphi-like compiler with certain limitations). The DLL is written by me in Delphi 2010.

So the problem is - I can't get rid of access violations when I pass a Widestring array to DLL. Whatever I tried - I got AVs sooner or later. And even if not, my statically loaded DLL was locked by host app, I can't rename or delete the DLL, so something is wrong.

There's an example of code which describes how to do it using interfaces (new for me which I liked a lot). Works like a charm and the DLL file is not locked.

**General definitions (DLL + EXE)**

```
type
  // Your "structure"
  TSomething = record
    A: Integer;
    S: WideString;
  end;

  // Your "structure list"
  TSomethingArray = array of TSomething;

  // The DLL and the EXE exchange data via Interface
  IArray = interface
  ['{EE7F1553-D21F-4E0E-A9DA-C08B01011DBE}'] // press Ctrl+Shift+G to generate id
  // protected
    function GetCount: Integer; safecall;
    function GetItem(const AIndex: Integer): TSomething; safecall;
  // public
    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property Items[const AIndex: Integer]: TSomething read GetItem; default;
  end;
```

**DLL**

```
// DLL, auxilary code:
type
  // IArray implementation, which will be passed from DLL to EXE
  TBaseArray = class(TInterfacedObject, IArray)
  protected
    FArray: TSomethingArray;
    function GetCount: Integer; safecall;
    function GetItem(const AIndex: Integer): TSomething; safecall;
  end;

  // Copying an array - for static and open arrays
  TArray = class(TBaseArray)
  public
    constructor Create(const AArray: array of TSomething);
  end;

  // We don't have to copy an array for dynamic arrays
  TArrayRef = class(TBaseArray)
  public
    constructor Create(const AArray: TSomethingArray);
  end;

  // We could create 1 class instead of 3 (TArray),
  // but with 2 constructors (CreateByArr, CreateByDynArr).
  // Or even with 1 constructor, if you work with 1 type of array.
  // But it doesn't really matter, it's a matter of convenience.
  // What really matters is a class which implements an interface.

{ TBaseArray }

function TBaseArray.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := Length(FArray);
end;

function TBaseArray.GetItem(const AIndex: Integer): TSomething;
begin
  Result := FArray[AIndex];
end;

{ TArray }

constructor TArray.Create(const AArray: array of TSomething);
var
  ArrIndex: Integer;
begin
  inherited Create;

  SetLength(FArray, Length(AArray));
  for ArrIndex := 0 to High(AArray) do
    FArray[ArrIndex] := AArray[ArrIndex];
end;

{ TArrayRef }

constructor TArrayRef.Create(const AArray: TSomethingArray);
begin
  inherited Create;

  FArray := AArray;
end;

// DLL, applied code:

function DoSomething1: IArray; stdcall;
var
  A: array[0..2] of TSomething;
begin
  // Some operations with array...
  A[0].A := 1;
  A[0].S := 'S1';
  A[1].A := 2;
  A[1].S := 'S2';
  A[2].A := 3;
  A[2].S := 'S3';

  // Returning result
  Result := TArray.Create(A); // <- An array is copied here
end;

function DoSomething2: IArray; stdcall;
var
  A: TSomethingArray;
begin
  // Some operations with array...
  SetLength(A, 3);
  A[0].A := 1;
  A[0].S := 'S1';
  A[1].A := 2;
  A[1].S := 'S2';
  A[2].A := 3;
  A[2].S := 'S3';

  // Returning result
  Result := TArrayRef.Create(A); // An array isn't copied here, only reference counting
  // We could also write:
  // Result := TArray.Create(A);
  // but the array would be copied in this case
end;

exports
  DoSomething1, DoSomething2;
```

**EXE**

```
function DoSomething1: IArray; stdcall; external 'Project2.dll';
function DoSomething2: IArray; stdcall; external 'Project2.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  A: IArray;
  X: Integer;
begin
  A := DoSomething1; // or DoSomething2

  for X := 0 to A.Count - 1 do
    OutputDebugString(PChar(IntToStr(A[X].A) + ' ' + A[X].S));
end;
```

This code works fine with my host app (when all OOP logic is in DLL). But I need the data to be passed from EXE to DLL.

So I swapped the code and the EXE became the 'heavier' part, everything was fine too, but only if both DLL and EXE are written in Delphi 2010.

If I use my host app and a static array, the compiler in my host app reports 'incompatible types' error at string in DoSomething1:

```
Result := TArray.Create(A);
```

When I write

```
Result := TArray.Create(A) as IArray;
```

it compiles but the app crashes.

If I use dynamic array, the compiler reports "Access violation at address 0D92062B. Read of address FFFFFFF8" here:

```
function TBaseArray.GetItem(const AIndex: Integer): TSomething;
begin
  Result := FArray[AIndex];
end;
```

**The author of this code said that if we want to pass data from EXE to DLL we need to use callbacks. And I just swapped the code. Maybe this is the problem? If so, how should I use callbacks here?**

Comment: I don't understand what part fails. You say *This code works fine with my host app (when all OOP logic is in DLL).* So what's the problem?

Comment: The code in my post implies passing data from DLL to EXE. It works fine. But I need to pass the data in the opposite direction. It becomes troublesome. Passing data in the opposite direction works only if both DLL and EXE are written in Delphi 2010 (and my host app uses some version of a very limited delphi-like compiler, 'Pax compiler' AFAICT).

Comment: Why don't you cut this down and show the exact program that fails, and nothing more. Because it looks like you showed the program that works.

Comment: [Here's DLL code](http://pastie.org/private/hzlfncxvxoli850awoyy2w)
;   

[Here's EXE code that fails in host app](http://pastie.org/private/d9t2xk9vecksnlidjfx8w)
;

[Here's test Delphi 2010 EXE code that works](http://pastie.org/private/2ua2vf7cufzeyutrvxvgog)

Comment: I don't want to follow off site links. Never mind. Somebody else will help you.

Comment: Ok, the code was just too long to paste here. But thanks anyway.

Comment: The code won't be too long when you cut down to an MCVE.

Comment: Your two EXE sources are substantively the same I see, however the first one calls the DLL in the unit/DPR's initialization section. Perhaps COM hasn't been initialised yet by that point?

Comment: Why are you using `safecall`? It makes sense only if you call methods of an external COM object returning `HResult` type.

Comment: @Chris I don't see any COM

Comment: Maybe there is an easier way to pass data from exe to dll and not suffer from AVs? 
All I need is to pass 2 string arrays and a couple of integer values in a loop (actually any data structures not necessarily arrays).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I see BSTRs. Do they not require CoInitialized/-Ex called? (Maybe they don't)

Comment: @user246408 - I disagree. Using safecall is an easy way to marshal unhandled exceptions between module boundaries, in effect.

Comment: @Chris I don't think BSTR apis need com initialized. I don't think you need to init com to use Delphi WideString. For instance in a console app.

Comment: @Elvari - it isn't clear to me whether there is just a bug in paxCompiler here. Not saying there is, but have you tried writing a client EXE in another version of Delphi, or if you don't have one, FPC?

Comment: @Chris there's no EXE in fact, there's a paxCompiler script window where I launch delphi-like code and load a DLL. Maybe there's a bug in it. I've managed to make some working code with interfaces and after several minutes of intensive testing got exactly the same AV error as without using interfaces yesterday. So.. apparently they are not helpful for me right now. I'm going to thoroughly check my code once again from the very beginning. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: The problem is in memory manager - you can not think that different compiler (Delphi and especially other compilers like C++ ..) have the same memory manager logic. Because of that -you have not problem - if both dll and exe are is written in the same delphi version. Change code to use same calling convention like stdcall and exchangable data types

Comment: @Livius - that's not it. Using safecall *is* using stdcall under the covers, and (on Windows) passing interfaces that only use primitive or system-managed types (like BSTRs) are fine.